Showing $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{iz \cos \theta} \, d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta.$
Can anyone help me understand why $J_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{iz \cos \theta} \, d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta.$
Using Euler's formula it's obvious that $$J_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{iz \cos \theta} \, d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \cos \theta) \, d\theta.$$
But I am not understanding why $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \cos \theta) \, d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta.$

Note that
$$\int_{0}^\pi\cos (z\cos \theta) d\theta
=2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos (z\cos \theta) d\theta \\= 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos (z\sin \theta) d\theta= \int_0^{\pi}\cos (z\sin \theta) d\theta
$$

The function $\cos$ is even, so $\cos(z\cos\theta)=\cos(-z\cos\theta)$. Over the interval $[0,\pi]$, $\sin\theta$ is the same as $|\cos\theta|$ with the pieces rearranged. In more detail:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\cos(z\cos\theta)d\theta 
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(z\cos\theta)d\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi\cos(-z\cos\theta)d\theta\\
&= \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(z\sin\theta)d\theta + \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(z\sin\theta)d\theta\\
&= \int_0^\pi \cos(z\sin\theta)d\theta
\end{align}
Edit: OP said the bit using Euler's formula is obvious. For future readers, I'll add why, i.e. dropping the $\sin$ part of $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$, which uses similar reasoning to the above, now with a touch more detail:
\begin{align}
  \int_0^\pi \sin(z\cos\theta) d\theta
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(z\cos\theta)d\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin(z\cos\theta)d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(z\cos\theta)d\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin[-z\cos(\pi-\theta)]d\theta & \cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos(\theta)\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(z\cos\theta)d\theta + \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin[-z\cos\chi]d\chi & \chi=\pi-\theta, d\chi=-d\theta\\
&= 0 & \sin\text{ is odd}
\end{align}

Did you use the argument that on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ $\cos{\theta},$ is equal to $\sin{\theta}$ on the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and vice-varsa.

Yes, exactly. On the vice-versa part "$-\cos\theta$" on the interval $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$ is equal to $\sin\theta$ on the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$. In more detail, you could write $-\cos\theta=\sin(\theta-\frac\pi2)$ and change variables, similar to what I did in the edit. Let me know if you want me to write that out.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\left.\cos \theta\right|{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}&=\left.\sin \theta\right|{[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]}, ~~\text{and}\
-\left.\cos \theta\right|{[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]}&=\left.\sin \theta\right|{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I get it, We can just simply state this and change the integral limit. Thank you so much!

$$
\int_0^\pi e^{i z \cos \theta} d \theta
= \int_0^\pi \cos (z \cos \theta)+i \int_0^\pi \sin (z \cos \theta) \theta
$$
For the last integral, let $\theta \mapsto \pi-\theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\pi \sin (z \cos \theta) d \theta & =\int_0^\pi \sin (-z \cos \theta) d \theta \\
& =-\int_0^\pi \sin (z \cos \theta) d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$
We can get $$
\int_0^\pi \sin (z \cos \theta) d \theta=0
$$
and hence $$\int_0^\pi e^{i z \cos \theta} d \theta
= \int_0^\pi \cos (z \cos \theta)$$
