Hankel transformation formula derivation. (Verification! )
Suppose that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a radially symmetric.  Show that:
$$
\widetilde{f}(y) = \int_0^\infty J_0(r|y|) f(r) r \, dr,
$$
where $J_0(z)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{iz \cos \theta} d\theta,$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.
My Approach:
Using the similar approach (See)
\begin{equation}\label{4}
\begin{array}{ll}
J_0(z)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi  \cos(z \sin \theta)  d\theta.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Notice that, this yields $J_0(-z)=J_0(z).$
Thus,
\begin{equation}\label{5}
\begin{array}{ll}
J_0(|z|)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{i |z| \cos \theta} \, d\theta =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi  \cos(z \sin \theta)  d\theta.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Now , since cosine function is even we have \begin{equation}\label{6}
\begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta&=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}  \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta+\frac{1}{\pi} \int_\pi^{2\pi}  \cos(z \sin \theta)  \, d\theta
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
Now, use the substitution $ \theta = 2\pi - \theta' $ in the second integral. This substitution maps $ \theta = \pi $ to $ \theta' = \pi $, and $ \theta = 2\pi $ to $ \theta' = 0 $. Also, $ d\theta = -d\theta' $, so the integral becomes:
$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta = \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin (2\pi - \theta')) \, d\theta'.
$$
Since, $ \sin(2\pi - \theta') = -\sin(\theta') $, we get:
$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta = \int_0^\pi \cos(-z \sin \theta') \, d\theta'.
$$
Using the even property of cosine function, the integral becomes:
$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta = \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin \theta') \, d\theta'.
$$
Thus, we have
\begin{equation}
    \label{7}
    \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(z \sin \theta) \, d\theta .
\end{equation}
Finally, we have $\int_0^{2\pi}  e^{i|z|\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta =2\pi J_0(|z|). $
Now, the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ is given by:
$$
\widetilde{f}(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x) e^{- i x \cdot y} \, dx,
$$
where $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2 $, and $ x \cdot y = |x||y|\cos\theta $.
Since $f(x) = f(r)$ is radially symmetric, we switch to polar coordinates. Then, the Fourier transform becomes:
$$
\widetilde{f}(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} f(r) e^{- i r |y| \cos(\theta)} r \, d\theta \, dr.
$$
Using Fubini's theorem we can change the order of the integral and write it as
\begin{equation}\label{a}
\widetilde{f}(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty f(r)r\left(\int_0^{2\pi}  e^{- i r |y| \cos(\theta)} \, d\theta \right)\, dr.
\end{equation}
Using the result from the first part I hope we have the proof. Correct me if I am wrong here.

All looks OK to me.

$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\pm i a\cos\theta}d\theta = 2\pi J_0(|a|)$, so
\begin{align}
\tilde{f}(y) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty f(r)r\left(\int_0^{2\pi}  e^{- i r |y| \cos(\theta)} \, d\theta \right)\, dr\\
&= \int_0^\infty f(r)r J_0(r|y|) dr
\end{align}
as required.
Edit: To show $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\pm i a\cos\theta}d\theta = 2\pi J_0(|a|)$, start with the generating function for Bessel functions, $e^{(x/2)(t-1/t)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)t^n$, use $t=e^{i\theta}$ to get $e^{ix\sin\theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)e^{in\theta}$. Integrating,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix\sin\theta}d\theta=2\pi J_0(x) + \sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne 0}^\infty J_n(x)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{in\theta}d\theta = 2\pi J_0(x).$$
$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix\sin\theta}d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ix\cos\theta}d\theta$ since we are integrating over a full period.

Is this a well known result? I am trying to understand how it is true.

Yes, it's the integral representation of the Bessel function $J_0(x)$. I added a sketch of how it's shown, following Arfken+Weber. Let me know if you need help with any of the steps.

Another integral representation is $J_0(x)=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin\theta)$, which can be used to obtain the above with the result of your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5006339/7515, extending the latter to $[0,2\pi]$.

I edited the whole thing using my previous result. Would you mind checking it and correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!
